# RegularExpression Validator doesn't display error message, if invalid data is entered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used below code for validating a textbox in .cshtml file. But when I enter invalid data in the textbox, RegularExpression Validator doesn't display error message.

Index.cshtml:

```
@model RockwellEntityDemo.Areas.Report.Models.StagewiseDCReport

<table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DCNoSONoFilter", "StagewiseDelivery", new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions
                           {
                               InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
                               HttpMethod = "POST",
                               UpdateTargetId = "stagewisedeliverylist"
                           }))
                    {                          
                        <table>     
                            <tr>
                                <th>DC No: </th>                                    
                                <th>   
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DC_NO, new { id="DC_NO" })                                                                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DC_NO, new { id="DC_NO" })
                                    <font color="red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DC_NO)</font>  
                                </th>                                    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <input type="submit" value="View" id="BtnSubmit" />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                            
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

In Model Class, I have declared DC_NO as string:

```
public class StagewiseDCReport 
{
    [DisplayName("DC No")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}$", ErrorMessage = "Alphanumeric Only")] 
    public string DC_NO { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class StagewiseDeliveryController : MasterController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DCNoSONoFilter(string DC_NO)
    {      
        IEnumerable<StagewiseDCReport> dcms = null;
        //StagewiseDCReport dcms= new StagewiseDCReport();
        try
        {               
            dcms = from t in db.DC_MASTER
                    join t0 in db.CUSTOMER_MASTER on t.CUSTOMER_MASTER.CUS_CODE equals t0.CUS_CODE
                    where
                        1 == 1 && (DC_NO == "" || t.DC_NO == DC_NO)                                                      
                    select new StagewiseDCReport
                    {
                        DC_NO = t.DC_NO,
                        ...                      
                    };                    

            return PartialView("StagewiseDeliveryList",dcms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "Some error occured while loading the page contact help desk";
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "StagewiseDelivery-DCNoSONoFilter-POST");
            return PartialView("StagewiseDeliveryList", dcms);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your incoming model on the view should be - `@model RockwellEntityDemo.Areas.Report.Models.StagewiseDCReport`, you shouldn't be having `IEnumarable` because you are not iterating the model anywhere in the `cshtml`.

Comment: Your model is a collection, not a single object. You need a `for` loop (or `EditorTemplate` to display each item in the collection

Comment: What do you mean by `how can i validate?` are you planning to get `IEnumerable` or just single model? If it is single model, then changing the incoming model will work. or else as @StephenMuecke said, you need to use `for loop` to iterate the model and display the TextBoxFor and corresponding `ValidationMessageFor` for each instance.

Comment: Your manually generated `<input id="DC_NO" name="DC_NO" type="text" />` has no relationship to your model so will not bind back to your model when you submit. Are you wanting to display and edit a single `StagewiseDCReport` object or a collection of `StagewiseDCReport` objects?

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening. Edit your question to append the new code you have tried (we cannot guess what other errors you may have made). And use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DC_NO)` (not manual html) is you want client side validation

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts for client side validation? You not doing any server side validation so that will not generate any error messages.

Comment: No. I didn't use any scripts for validation.

Comment: How do I apply server side validation in the above code to generate the error message.

Comment: @LimnaD'silva. You need to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` for client side validation. And your not passing back you model (the parameter of your post method is just a `string`, not `StagewiseDCReport` so you wont get server side validation, But you can change the method to `public ActionResult DCNoSONoFilter(StagewiseDCReport model)` and check `ModelState.IsValid`